# Using vpn client inside azure vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn, checkpoint

I am trying to use a VPN Client (Check Point Endpoint Security) from withing an azure VM. Everything works fine, when the VM is not part of an azure VPN. When it is the connection cannot be made (negotiation with site failed). I tried adding several endpoints (https://forums.checkpoint.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=15352) - still nothing. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out to be a software (client) problem.

Comment: can you elaborate?